# Is it possible to filter records of one index from another index in elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, kibana-7

Lets say I have 100 records in index1 and 10 records in index2. And I want to get like this:

```
select * from index1 where id not in (select id from index2)
```

Can we have the same above query in elasticsearch or is it even possible.

I have tried multiple index search and it is working, however I have no clue for filter part. I am using elasticsearch-7.3.0

Please suggest!

Below query I have tried:

```
GET index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
        "id.keyword": {
            "index" : "index2",
            "id" : "_all",
            "path" : "id"
        }
    }
        }
      ]
    } 

  }
}
```

Comment: `I have tried multiple index search and it is working`. Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Soumendra: I have tried with updated query its working only for 1 or some ids. I need to filter out around millions of ids from another index. Updated my tried and tested query.

Answer (score 0):

**Sub query** not support by **ES**.You can achieve the result by using two query.

**Query 1:** To fetch all id values from **index 2**

```
    POST index2/_search
    {
      "_source": [
        "id"
      ]
    }
```

**Query 2:** To fetch all record in **index 1** **with != conditions**

```
POST index1/_search
{
  "query": {

    "bool": {

      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "id": [
              "val1",
              "val2"
            ]
          }

        }
      ]

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, just wanted to understand in your second query how "id" is identified from index index1, I believe these ids only from index2 only. I think filteration is still not happening pls correct me if I am wrong:  "must_not": [{"terms": {"id": ["val1","val2"]}}]

Comment: I changed the index name .In the first query we find all the ids from index 2 after that  we use second query to fetch all records from index 1 with conditional operator(first query index 2 result i.e  id's values)

Comment: ok. so how I am gonna execute the query. Simultaneously or one by one because in the index2 I have millions of ids.  I can't put every id manually :(. Pls suggest

Comment: You can run the query one by one, but millions of ids we can't do it manually.so write some auto script using python or node js to run the query. Millions of id make your query very much slow and your application will crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TermsLookup, this will let you add values in "where clause" from another index